# OSX with xcode 5 - Application not behaving the same way when xcode is open using sqlcipher

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, sqlcipher

Disclaimer: Not sure whether or not this is a linking issue between my project and sqlcipher, my lack of knowledge towards how a program is run when xcode is open, or if my code is incorrect.

I have a working mac osx application when it is run on xcode that encrypts and decrypts database files using sqlcipher.

The only problem is, is that when I export the program to a non-signed mac osx application or when I run the .app file made from xcode, I get the an error code **14** (Unable to open the database file) while the application is running (sqlite3open gives SQLITE_OK)

```
attachCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"ATTACH DATABASE \"%@\" AS outputDB KEY '%@';", outFile, key];

if ((sqlerror = sqlite3_exec(db, ((const char*) [attachCmd UTF8String]), NULL, NULL, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK) {
    ...
}
```

I am not sure whether I have static library linking issues or my code/sqlcipher's code issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: my simulator had access to the sandbox while release applications did not.

So i had to add in the capabilities tab of project settings sandbox to fix this.